# Separating a char from a String?

Tags: java

I am trying to separate the char from the following examples of inputs:

C450.00
C30
P100

I would like to have the char such as "C" or "P" separated so I can work with them alone, 
as well as the "450.00", "30", and "100" separated as ints. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: separate them using their ASCII values...

Comment: It's a single `String` case or there are many possibilities?

Comment: You can access String objects as arrays.

Comment: Can please show the expected result? Do you need the char or the numbers?

Answer (score 1):

If the `String` are always that format:

```
char ch = yourString.charAt(0);
Double d = Double.valueOf(yourString.substring(1, yourString.length()));
```

***NOTE:*** I used a `Double` because you have dots `.` in the `String`. You can convert from `double` to `int` easily if you won't have any decimals. But that depends on your needings.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the String with whitespace as delimiter. Afterwards use substring on every part of your string. Now you have the C and the 450.0 as Stings. Finally cast the second part of your substring into an integer and you are done.

to split:

```
String[] parts = string.split(" ");
```

to substring:

```
String first = parts[0].substring(0, 1);
String second = parts[0].substring(1);
```

Comment: @MarkoStojsic If you dont have a steadily format, it will be more difficult.

Comment: @MarkoStojsic In fact, you need a delimiter to know the begin and the end of each part.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know what are you looking for in the given String (eg. You know you are looking for the C character ) , you could use the Regex Pattern : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library org.​apache.​commons.​lang3.​StringUtils 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi

public static String[] split(String str, String separatorChars)

```
    String[] res = StringUtils.split("C450.00 C30 P100", "CP ");        
    for (String r : res) {
        System.out.println(r);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the separate 'numbers' are always in this format:

```
C130
P90
V2.0
```

that is, a single letter followed by a number (possibly with a floating point).

```
String input = "C450.00 C30 P100";

// First split the string by a space
String[] parts = input.split(" ");

for (String part : parts) {
    // Get the character from the string
    char ch = part.charAt(0);

    // Get the remains of the string and convert it to a double
    double number = Double.parseDouble(part.substring(1));

    // Then do something with 'ch' and 'number'
}
```

---

If the separate parts possibly have two or more letters in it, e.g. `AC130`, then you need another approach:

```
String input = "AC130 AG36 P90";
String[] parts = input.split(" ");

for (String part : parts) {
    /* Do some regular expression magic. */
}
```

See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html.

Answer (score 0):

here some piece of code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a = "C450.00 C30 P100";
    String letters = "";
    String numbers = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if ((a.charAt(i) + "").matches("\\d|\\.| ")) {
            numbers += a.charAt(i);
        } else {
            letters += a.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    String[] strArray = numbers.split(" ");
    int[] numberArray = new int[strArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        numberArray[i] = (int) Double.parseDouble(strArray[i]);
        System.out.println(numberArray[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(letters);
}
```

the result is `numberArray`, which contains all numbers as ints.
and `letters`, which is a String with all letters.